# MySQL string replace using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Is there a way in `SQLAlchemy` to perform a `MySQL` string replace. I'd like to find a way to do the following in SQLAlchemy core.

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_field = REPLACE(your_field, 'from_str', 'to_str')
WHERE your_field LIKE '%from_str%'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, read more about it on [Column Elements and Expressions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func), but the key point is to use `func.MY_FUNCTION`:

```
func.REPLACE(YourTable.your_field, 'from_str', 'to_str')
```

If you perform update from query, it might look like this:

```
updated_rows = (
    session.query(YourTable)
    .filter(YourTable.your_field.like('%est%'))
    .update({YourTable.your_field: func.replace(YourTable.your_field, 'from_str', 'to_str')},
            synchronize_session=False)
    )
print("Updated {} rows".format(updated_rows))
```